# d3 - apply transformations to different elements when dragging

Tags: d3.js

I have the code that is in the following [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/navitu/1/edit?js,output), I have dragging enabled for either of the circles at the end of a line.

What I want to do is move the other elements so the line moves with the circle.

How can I apply other transformations to other elements in the ondrag handler?

I just want advice and not code because this is a good learning exercise for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the many ways:

Add a style to the circle to mark the *start* and *end* of a circle.

```
var line = {
    start: {x: 2, y: 3, type: "start"},
    finish: {x: 14, y: 6, type: "end"} 
  };
//adding this type to the class of the circle
var circles = g
     .selectAll('circle')
     .data(lineData)
     .enter().append("circle")
     .attr('class', function(d){return "circle "+d.type;})
     .attr('cx', function(d){return xScale(d.x);})
     .attr('cy', function(d){return yScale(d.y);})
     .attr('r', 10)
     .style('fill', 'red')
     .call(drag);
```

Then on drag updating the lines x1/y1 x2/y2 depending on the class of the circle dragged.

```
if (d3.select(this).classed("start")){
          //update the start position of line
          d3.select(".line").attr("x1", d3.event.x).attr("y1", d3.event.y);
        } else {
          d3.select(".line").attr("x2", d3.event.x).attr("y2", d3.event.y);
```

Full code [here](http://jsbin.com/xixuvezeta/1/edit?js,output).